# access a non static structure from a static function

Tags: c++, linked-list, static-methods

I am trying to access HashTable which is a non static  member from a static function Initialize()

This is how my code looks like. 
I get the following error when i run this

"undefined reference to `Hash::HashTable'"
  Is there any way i can access is from Initialize with the same definitions for HashTable.

---

```
class Hash
{

private:
  static const int tableSize = 10;
  struct item
  {
       string name;
       item* next;
  };
  static item* HashTable[tableSize];
public:
  static void Initialize();
  static int Hash(string key);

};
----------------------------------------------------------------------------



--------------------------------hash.cpp------------------------------------

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include "hash.hpp"

using namespace std;


hash::Initialize()
{
      for(int i=0;i<tableSize;i++)
      {
            HashTable[i] =  new item; //Gives an error
            HashTable[i]->name = "empty";//Gives an error
            HashTable[i]->next = NULL;
      }
}

int hash::Hash(string key)
{
    int hash=0;
    int index=0;
    for(int i=0;i<key.length();i++)
    {
           hash = (hash + (int)key[i]);
    }
    index = hash % tableSize;
    cout<<"Index-"<<index<<endl;
    return index;

}



int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    Hash:Initialize();
    Hash::PrintTable();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: look up what one definition rule is. static members need to be instantiated in one translation unit. simply including the header file is declaration, not instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error reported from the linker, not the compiler. You forgot to provide a definition for `HashTable` in your code. To fix, add

```
hash::item* hash::HashTable[hash::tableSize];
```

to `hash.cpp`.

Comment: What?  That should have been included automatically by the `#include "hash.hpp"` statement, no?

Comment: @abiessu **No** read your C++ basics. static data members have to be *defined* somewhere. The class definition only *declares* them.

Comment: @Walter: my mistake.  It's been a while since I've used a static member variable...